# How do trigonometric identities apply to this equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

COuld someone please explain how we go from:

$\frac{1}{4}\cos{2x}$

to

$\frac {\cos^2{x}}{2}$

Using trigonometric identities. I am pretty sure the two statements are equivalent but have no idea how.

Comment: The two are not equivalent (try $x=\pi$). Is this part of a larger problem (e.g. an integral)?

Comment: Yes it is. Integrating $-\frac{1}{2}\sin{2x}$ by hand yields the first expression, while integrating on Mathematica gives the second. I did in fact use exactly $u=2x$ when I did it by hand

Comment: So I dont know why they are different....

Comment: They actually differ by a constant :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the two expressions are not equal. However, using the identity
$$ \cos{2x} = 2\cos^2{x}-1 $$
you can get that the two quantities differ by a constant. Hence, indefinite integration can lead you to both answers, which is okay, since indefinite integrals are only defined up to a constant.

Answer (score 3):

cos$(2x)=2$cos$^2(x) - 1$, so $\frac{1}{4}$cos$(2x)$=$\frac{1}{2}$cos$^2(x)-\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, these are simply not equivalent. For instance: $\frac{1}{4}cos(2\times0)=\frac{1}{4}$, whilst $\frac{1}{2}cos(0)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from :$\frac {1}{4} cos2x$.

$\frac {1}{4} (2cos^2x-1)$.

You might have some error in your question.